# Why All for One never stole One for All?

Tags: my-hero-academia

All for One is the most powerful superhuman with the exception of All Might who has the quirk One for All. If All for One has the quirk who makes him able to steal quirks, and All Might is the only person he can't defeat, why All for One doesnt steal One for All and let All Might quirkless to be able to defeat him?

Comment: I don't think we know enough about All for One quirk to figure it out. I doubt he can steal quirks instantly. It might be process, that requires specific physical contact, or any other specific condition.

Answer (score 7):

First, What is **One For All**?

> One For All is the union of two Quirks: A Quirk that stockpiles power, and a Quirk that could be transferred to others. This mutation was caused by the Quirk, All For One.

**One For All** cannot be stolen by force:

> One For All will not transfer to a new recipient unless its user wishes it, thus One For All cannot be forcibly stolen. For example, the Hero Killer Stain ingested Izuku's blood, but did not inherit One For All because Izuku did not wish it. However, this does not mean One For All cannot be forcibly passed on.

Why **All for One** doesn't steal One for All and let All Might quirkless to be able to defeat him?

Apart from the reason why can't **One For All** be stolen, you can see that:

> After One For All is transferred to the recipient, the previous One For All user can still use the "leftover embers" of One For All, and thus can still access One For All's power. However, these leftover embers will not last for long, and the previous One For All will slowly run out of the embers, resulting in the previous user losing One For All completely.

**All Might** has the **"leftovers"** of **One For All** but soon or later he will loose One For All completely, **the user with One For All now is Izuku**, if the Quirk was to be taken it had to be from Izuku and not All Might.

Source: [Wiki](http://bokunoheroacademia.wikia.com/wiki/One_For_All)

Comment: The "One for All cannot be stolen by force" logic doesn't really apply here.  That seems to only apply to the "passing it along by consuming DNA" method of transference.  Most other quirks normally can't be stolen or transferred at all... until All for One shows up.

Comment: @kaine I'm afraid I didn't understand your logic, One For All cannot be taken unless the owner wants it (can't be done by force), what is wrong with that logic?

Comment: By "cannot be stolen" it only meant you can't like steal Izuku's hair, eat it, then gain One for All. I'm pretty sure All for One would still be able to steal it.

Comment: All for One has a completely different transference mechanism than One for Alls normal method so why should rules for one transfer mechanism effect the other.   You cant steal a house. You can take a mobile home if the owner gives you the keys. The keys have no bearing on the bank foreclosing on the home taking ownership from you.

Comment: Saying "why should it be this way?" is conjecture. It MAY be that All for One can't steal it, but they only ever said in canon as far as I've read that it can't be stolen by stealing blood, hair, whatever from Izuku. It is definitely true though that after All Might passed on One for All, it could no longer be stolen from him.

Comment: I also thought what @kaine said. That the logic of the user has to be willing to pass it to "passing it along by consuming DNA" doesnt apply to someone with a stealing quirk. I also think that for some reason (that might not be that one) All for One can't steal it anyway. May be it's related to that condition it's said online All for One said, that once he transfered a quirk after a while he can't recover it. Since he passed one of the quirks of One for All and time passed may be that's why he can't recover it.

Comment: Maybe stealing quirks works in a way where it consumes DNA

Answer (score 3):

I think there is a combination of reasons:

1. Originally, One for All was a completely useless quirk that would have been undetectable. All it did was allow itself to be passed to someone else. This quirk was combined with another quirk that allows the user to store up power and use it as super strength, courtesy of All for One. All for One actually was the one who gave the original possessor of One for All the second quirk, most likely not knowing of the existence of One for All or that the two would combine in such a powerful manner.
2. Once One for All became as it is now, it would have been difficult for All for One to simply take it. The owner of One for All would have resisted using his now quite powerful quirk. Also, in the beginning, when One for All had less energy stored, All for One also probably had stolen fewer quirks. If he took time to steal more, One for All would have become more powerful by storing more energy. So they may have been evenly matched at each encounter despite them both acquiring more power over time.
3. One for All only is as powerful is it is now because it was passed down by many users who all stored up energy using One for All.  This means that immediately after gaining that second quirk, the original owner of One for All would only have seemed exactly as expected, rather than unexpectedly powerful, as it turned out to be.  Remember, All for One gave the original owner of One for All the second quirk. He intended for him to have it and use it, back when it was less powerful. Only now that it has passed to others has it become apparent how much potential the two quirks had.
4. Furthermore, it might have had to pass between many people to maximize its potential as its not entirely clear if a single long lived person could attain the same result. I don't think One for All would even necessarily be interested in a quirk that he had to share around in order for it to reach its maximum potential. Perhaps now that it has reached this level of power he would be interested in stealing it if he could, however.

Comment: Also, can I say how terrible it is that he called the powers One for All and All for One? I'm having a devil of a time keeping them straight.

Answer (score 0):

There are ways to get around the limitation of one for all not being able to be stolen by force, by using a mind control quirk for instance.  We already saw Deku being controlled by Hitoshi Shinso, so in the future, a new All for One user might overtake the One for all user with a powerful Mind control Quirk, and force him to give up his power, ushering in an age of destruction.
  The problem with Hitoshi Shinso's power is that it's not really "Mind control" but body control.  A True mind control quirk would make the person controlled actually believe that they want to do the things they are being forced to do after the trigger condition is met, so resisting would basically be impossible.  This would make for the most Nefarious version of All for one, where in the final battle, One for all thinks he has the upper hand, when he triggers the mind control condition, and is forced to give up his power, probably all on Nationwide television.

Answer (score 0):

I think we might have an answer for this,

> In the movie Heroes Rising, Nine, who has a weaker version of All For One tries to steal Midoriya's quirk. He can't do it because he can only have 9 quirks and One for All holds several quirks, but for trying to do so (steal a quirk) he needs to be in contact with the holder of the quirk. So the reason why All for One never stole One for All might be he could never grab or catch and hold All Might to steal it